# How to post on Facebook all friends wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**I have an app which is able to**

1. Post on a user's wall
2. `Publish_stram` and `read_friendlists` permissions
3. Able to get a user's friends list

and get the list like

```
{
     "name": "example1",
     "id": "100003373457"
  },
  {
     "name": "example2",
     "id": "100003377"
  },
```

How do I make a loop to post on all of a user's Facebook friends' walls with `sleep()`?

Comment: Note: this is not a duplicate question because no question can cover the all topics which i asked

Comment: Please only ask one thing at a time.

Comment: i ask all the things at once because i think one can easily answer them all and think if i posted different questions its wasted others time :)

Comment: why its yet not receive an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work :

```
foreach(friends_list as $x)
{
$ch = curl_init("https://graph.facebook.com/".$x[id]."/feed");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);



$post = array(
    "access_token"=>"..."
    "message"=>"SPAM",
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
sleep();
}
```

Comment: and what happen if one of my friend dont have the permission to post on his/her wall ?
i think the app will stop working and show the error as i face this problem in past i use try() can we also use in this

Comment: it will not stop working, this is just a post request.  You will see the response printed to the screen thats all.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. Your app will be considered as spam bot and banned from Facebook.

Comment: i am try to using with `rand() and sleep()` so maybe that don't take it spam

Comment: They probably will. I have done dozen of FB apps and have some intuition. Also read Facebook rules and recommendations for apps. Your app is probably validating some rules. I can't tell you for sure, because I don't know how exactly app works.

Comment: i have with posts almost 960+ posts daily 
in the format of 120+ posts after each 3 hours 
so whats your suggesstion i limit this app posting to 50 friends of per user ?